# Typing 'python' in terminal runs a python script and spits error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm taking a python course, I save exercise scripts in /this/is/where/I save/exercises/exercise.py.

Now whenever I type `python` in terminal it immediately gives me this:

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/this/is/where/I save/exercises/exercise.py'`

I know it's not found since I deleted the file. But why is python running that script whenever it runs? It's annoying.

**INFO**

Linux OS

Python2 and Python3 both show same error

Comment: Check the `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` for possible inadvertent inclusion of filename there.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling Python, or at least rebooting your machine?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, that is not something I would recommend. You should never screw with the system python on linux unless you are sure you know what you are doing

Comment: I assume you have set `PYTHONSTARTUP=/this/is/where/I/save/exercises/exercise.py` somewhere

Comment: Could you try runnning `echo $PYTHONSTARTUP` and see if you get the file tou mentioned in the output. If you get it in output, it's causing the issue.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, yes! This is it! How has this changed? and how do I change it back? What's the default?

Comment: @barunsthakur, Exactly. It shows the exercise file.

Comment: @Mars, how did you set `PYTHONSTARTUP` ?

Comment: @Padraic, the OS info was added after my comment. Indeed, the default Python install on Linux systems is best left alone.

Comment: @Mars unset `PYTHONPATH` and you are good to go.

Comment: I'm never heard of this variable before now, @PadraicCunningham. Although I wouldn't trust my memory honestly. I may have done something before then forgot. Forgiveness is good, and help is better :)

Comment: @Mars, you probably set it in `.bashrc`, open the file and check, if it is there remove it and start a bash shell again and try python

Comment: @Mars I guarantee you set that variable some how .... python doesnt just do it :P and I think Padraic is right

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I swear I looked into `.bashrc` almost 3 times. I just was looking for the wrong thing. It even has my old self's comment that it's a "temp thing to remove later". Never postpone today's work to tomorrow. Thanks all. I need to see a doctor for my memory after this, lol.

Comment: @Mars,  you will have to start writing comments to remind you about your comments ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, lol, well said.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @JoranBeasley, @barunsthakur, @PadraicCunningham, and all.

I had `PYTHONSTARTUP` set in `.bashrc`.

May help forgetful people in the future.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on UNIX-like system, like Linux or Mac, I suspect you might have an alias or mis-configured PATH. Start investigating by running:

```
which python  # which program is run when you type in python?
```

And

```
alias         # what are the aliases for the shell?
```

Answer (score -1):

Python has a special script that is run on startup. On my platform it is located at */usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/sitecustomize.py* IIRC. You may want to check that file for any script calls to that directory. Also, if you are on a linux machine you could check */etc/bashrc* or */etc/profile.d*. If that doesn't help, try to update your question with more specific information.

Comment: there is also an environment_variable that you can set to run a script everytime you start the python shell